# Counting digits of a number in a certain interval

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop, infinite-loop

I have to make a c++ program which calculates if the number within the interval `[m=1000;n=1100]` has an even number of digits.

But using this program that I wrote, I get an endless loop.

```
int digits(int m, int n)
{
    int i, count_digits = 0;

    for(i = m; i < n; i++)
    {
        while(i != 0)
        {
            i = i/10;
            count_digits++;
        }
    }
    if(k%2 == 0) return count_digits;
}
```

Comment: what is k here ? and indent the code properly.

Comment: Can you give an example of expected returned result for a given input `m` and `n`? Also clarify what `k` is

Comment: if I understand the question currently you are trying to see if the length of the numbers in the range m-n are even? if so why not convert them to string and chak the length?

Answer (score 1):

Within the loop

```
for(i = m; i < n; i++)
{
    while(i != 0)
    {
        i = i/10;
        count_digits++;
    }
}
```

you are changing the variable i.

Introduce one more local variable

```
for(i = m; i < n; i++)
{
    int value = i;
    while(value != 0)
    {
        value /= 10;
        count_digits++;
    }
}
```

It seems you also need to reinitialize the variable `count_digits` in each iteration of the loop.

```
for(i = m; i < n; i++)
{
    int value = i;
    count_digits = 0;
    while(value != 0)
    {
        value /= 10;
        count_digits++;
    }
}
```

Pay attention to that your loop is executed in the range of values [m, n-1] instead of the range [m, n] as you wrote in your question.

Also it is unclear where the variable k used in this statement

```
if(k%2 == 0) return count_digits;
```

is declared.

I can guess that you need something like the following

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const int M = 1000;
    const int N = 1100;
    const int Base = 10;

    for ( int i = M; i <= N; i++ )
    {
        int value = i;
        size_t count_digits = 0;

        do 
        { 
            if ( value % Base != 0 ) ++count_digits; 

        } while ( value /= Base );

        if ( count_digits % 2 == 0 ) std::cout << i << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1001 1002 1003 1004 1005 1006 1007 1008 1009 1010 1020 1030 1040 1050 1060 1070 1080 1090 1100
```

In any case you can consider the program as a base for your program.

Comment: why to reinitialize the variable count_digits in each iteration of the loop ?

Comment: @nivpeled I think the program needs to output all the numbers with the even number of digits is not equal to 0. Otherwise I do not see the sense of the assignment.